# Game freezing every 10 seconds

Tags: imac, performance, games

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a legit question here, but I don't know where else to ask.

I have installed the Call of Duty 2 MAC version on my iMac. My system capabilities (RAM, processor, video) are way above the recommended requirements, so I would have expected the game to run smooth.

However, in-game, doesn't matter if I am in the main menu or playing, **it keeps freezing for about 2 seconds, every 10 seconds** or so. I have set the quality settings to maximum and minimum, and it's the same.

Clearly it has nothing to do with in-game quality settings, as it does this even while in the main menu.

Any idea what the problem might be? I suspect my computer (1.5 years old iMac, 2.7GHz i5, 8GB@1600MHz DDR3, GeForce GT 640M 512MB) has a problem... it does boot slower than when I bought it... and overall it's not as fast.

Comment: My guess would be you have a task or process running in the background (either intentionally or not) and it's accessing your system resources (probably your hard drive) every ~10 seconds.  Is your hard drive almost full?  Open Activity Monitor and spend some time looking for things that may be spiking disk activity.

Comment: @FlyingTrashcan Thanks, I will. It must be something permanent then, because it's the same even after a computer restart. Hope I can find it :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it doesn't use multi core as I have the same problem.
iMac 2011, 27″, 3.4 GHz i7, 6970M 2 GB, 12 GB RAM, 120 GB SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Your system seems to be good enough, but you can run the system check on [this site](https://www.gameagent.com/games/call-of-duty-2) to verify (under System Requirements).

Other steps to analyze the issue

- make sure no other applications are running (including menulets)
- run Activity Monitor while playing the game and have an eye on the CPU usage of the various processes
- contact [Aspyr Support](http://support.aspyr.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?utm_source=MacApp&utm_medium=SupportLink&utm_campaign=call-of-duty-2) and describe your problem